# Difference between export class and just class for react in declaration

Tags: reactjs

What does the export exactly do below in the declaration? When i remove it, nothing seems to change so i'm having trouble understanding it's significance.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'

export class PureComp extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        )
    }
}

export default PureComp
```

and

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'

class PureComp extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        )
    }
}

export default PureComp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
export default PureComp
```

you are exporting a *default export*, that consumers can use by doing

```
import PureComp from './file.js';
```

When you do

```
export class PureComp
```

you are exporting a *named export* that consumers can use by doing

```
import { PureComp } from './file.js';
```

Named exports are useful for when you want to export multiple things from the same file. Here, since you're already default exporting the class, creating a named export for the same thing probably isn't useful.

With your first code, consumers can use the named import `PureComp`. With your second code, there are no named exports, only a default export.

Comment: so if i remove the named export (i.e. class PureComp), I can't call it in a named export like in  'import { PureComp }' from './file.js'; It must be 'export class PureComp' for me to do so?

Comment: What would be the benefit of that versus just using a default export since you can call whatever whenever in that class any time? Seems limiting

Comment: Indeed. Another problem with default exports is that they make name consistency more difficult, eg it's very easy to do `import PureCom from './file.js'`. Using named exports always can make things more consistent when you sometimes want to export multiple things, and can reduce typos, which is why I prefer to always use them instead of default exports.